# Access to Model in a Java Model-View-Controller design

Tags: java, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I am developing an editor following the general MVC design: the model holds the data, the controller knows how to change it, and the view issues calls the controller to query and modify the model. For the sake of argument, let us use

```
public class Model {
    public Object getStuff(String id);
    public void setStuff(String id, Object value);    
}    

public interface Controller {
    public void execute(Command command);
    public void redo();
    public void undo();     
    public void save();
    public void load(File f);
}
```

The class that actually implements the controller holds a reference to the model; commands need to access it too, so they must all provide a `void execute(Model m);` interface that actually grants them this access only when needed.

However, views generally need access to the model - when building themselves and, later on, to listen for changes and refresh themselves accordingly. **I am afraid that adding a "Model getModel()" call to the Controller will result in a great temptation to bypass the `execute()` mechanism**; and I am not the only developer working on the project. Given this scenario, **how would you enforce an "all changes go through the controller" policy?**

Two alternatives I am considering:

- An interface called "ReadOnlyModel", returned by the getModel() call instead of the real model, that catches any such attempts.
- Lots of comments to clue incoming developers as to the Correct Way of Doing Things

Comment: Note: the actual model contains a lot more logic. I have reduced it to a bare minimum for the sake of example only.

Comment: Use [Business Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_object_(computer_science)) or [Data Transfer Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Transfer_Object) to provide data from the model layer to the view layer (via the controller). No need to directly access the model layer from the view.

Comment: @GriffeyDog: I take this as a vote for a ReadOnlyModel then, as you advocate using proxy classes that expose parts of the model without direct write-access.

Comment: Well, the BOs or DTOs can go both ways, again with the controller mediating. So, the view can get model data to display, have the user make updates and then have the controller package the new data into BOs or DTOs to send to the model layer for persistence. No "direct" write access from the view to the model, but indirectly via the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend modeling the access to the model as a set of classes.  For example, if the view needs to modify a customer's attributes, there would be a ModifyCustomerCommand class that would have as properties all of the information needed in order to perform the update.  The view would construct an instance of the class with values and pass it back to the controller which, in turn, would pass the command back to the model for the actual update.

A benefit from this approach is that each of these model access commands can implement undo behavior.  If the controller keeps an ordered collection of these commands as they get sent back to the model, the controller can back off the changes, one at a time, by invoking the undo method on the most recently executed command.

Comment: That is exactly what Command subclasses are doing right now. The question is how to provide access to the model for the different views. Direct access to the model classes seems inevitable. Is it really a bad thing?

Comment: The views don't access the model directly.  They use the command classes.  The command classes access the model directly in whatever manner you choose.  The command classes are a bridge between the model and the view.

Answer (score 0):

What if you take a look at Observer Pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern, your view only listen for events from model.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Already doing this (actually via event listeners, but listeners and observable are very, very similar).